# Combining types of data to pass to @include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Below, I have the variable `entryName` available to use to insert data into my `small-test` blade view by using `{{!! entryName !!}}`.

```php
@include('views.small-test', [
    'entryName' => $data['entryName'],
])
```

But how can I append a static string to the front of it? Would using `.` work to concatenate it like below?

```php
@include('views.small-test', [
    'entryName' => "Welcome".$data['entryName'],
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works.

According to the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views):

> Even though the included view will inherit all data available in the parent view, you may also pass an array of extra data to the included view:

```php
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

You can also format the `entryName` on server side and send the variable to the view, or, within your `small-test` view, show the message like this:

```html
Welcome, {!! $entryName !!}
```

Hope it helps.